# Are VS-Code insiders settings same as non-insiders version?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I had thought that the settings would sync to the same place for both of these. I'm using the plugin shan.code-settings-sync.

I tend to go back and forth between insiders and non insiders builds. Do most people keep settings the same between the two?